# Is the submodule of a finitely generated free module finitely generated?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

$R$ is a commutative ring with unit and $M$ is a finitely generated free $R$-module. Is the submodule of $M$ also finitely generated?

Comment: It's always a good idea to look at simple examples first. What about $M=R$?

Answer (score 8):

If this were true, we might look at any ring $R$, which is free and generated by $1$ as an $R$ module, and conclude that all its submodules were finitely generated. Thus we would have proven all commutative rings are Noetherian! (If you are unfamiliar with that characterization of Noetherian modules, [check out this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/173252/proof-of-m-noetherian-if-and-only-if-all-submodules-are-finitely-generated))

So you can see that it is not true, since there are non-Noetherian rings.

Andreas's example is a concrete illustration of this: he gave an example of a non-Noetherian ring with an ideal that isn't finitely generated.

Comment: In fact, all f.g. $R$ modules are Noetherian $R$-modules if and only if $R$ is Noetherian. You have shown the only if part, and the other part is (slightly) more involved.

Answer (score 4):

Think of the case when $R$ is the ring of polynomials in countably many variables $x_1, x_2, \dots$ over a field, $M = R$, and take as a submodule the ideal $(x_1, x_2, \dots )$.