# Given a short exact sequence, is the following true?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

Say $0 \to M_1 \to M_2 \to M_3 \to 0$ is a short exact sequence and each $M_i$ is an $R$-module. If $M_2$ is finitely generated, then so also is $M_1$?

Comment: No – unless $M_2$ is a *noetherian* $R$-module, e.g. if $R$ is a noetherian ring.

Answer (score 0):

Your question can be rephrased to the question: Is a submodule of a finitely generated module again finitely generated, because for $M_1\subset M_2$ the sequence
$$ 0\rightarrow M_1 \rightarrow M_2 \rightarrow M_1/ M_2\rightarrow 0 $$
is always exact.

This is known to be false in general. See the following question which has stronger assumptions on the ring and the module and it is still false.

[Is the submodule of a finitely generated free module finitely generated?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485000/is-the-submodule-of-a-finitely-generated-free-module-finitely-generated)